# UIView stuck in portrait mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autoresizingmask

I am having trouble starting the app in landscape mode. The view is always shown in portrait mode.

I have the following configured in the plist:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

The UIViewController is created in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.myViewController = [MyViewController alloc];

    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    myView = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.myViewController.view = myView;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.myViewController;
    self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Added shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to MyViewController.m

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

When the device is in portrait mode and the app starts, the status bar is in landscape mode. However when the UIView gets shown, it will end up in portrait mode. The same thing happens when the device is in landscape mode.

However, when I create the UIViewController in Interface Builder, it works.

Is this related to autoresizemasking because it didn't work when I add this in AppDelegate.m:

```
 myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight ;
```

Comment: are you developing for iOS 6 ??

Comment: Working on latest Xcode 4.5 and iOS 5.0

Comment: Looks like I forgot to init the UIViewController. It worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code in your `ViewController` :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

Comment: No difference as returning YES

Comment: return yes return the values of : 1- UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft, 2-UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight, 3-UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,4- UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Tried it in the ipad 6.0 simulator and it did worked. But not in iPad 5.0 simulator or my 5.1 device.

Comment: because of  myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight ;
  its for ios 6

Answer (score 0):

Use this to find orientation at startup..it will work correct:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
if (! UIDeviceOrientationIsValidInterfaceOrientation(orientation))
    orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
```

Then use this orientation to rotate your view

Answer (score 0):

In your code I found a syntax error, I think you mean myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
But this is the only mistake, your code works fine, the app starts and stay in Landscape mode, with or without myView.autoresizingMask

My environment:
xCode 4.5
device iPhone 4S with IOS 6.0

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it works on iOS6. I couldn't get it working on iOS 5/5.1 without the autoresizingMask.

Comment: With iPhone 3GS and Ios 5.1 (phone of my wife) I had to change - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
} instead returning YES like the next answer

Comment: That's weird, even changing that and without the autoresizingMask, I am still stuck in portrait mode. The status bar is on the right.